# How to access wordpress libraries online?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed my plugin and it perfectly works on localhost, but it does not work online because it does not find the libraries, how should I modify them to run the plugin.

```
require_once("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-load.php");

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
```

Comment: You need to update the `require_once()` function to load your own Wordpress load file.

Comment: @BenM, I know but how to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where your WP install is, but this should work:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```